# How to Install a new version of a font?

Tags: fonts

I have installed a font using Font Viewer, when a new version of the font showed up, I downloaded it, after hitting the "Install font", the button text changes to "Install failed". What to do?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a Ubuntu bug.  See the bug report relating to it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/418633)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `fc-list` to find a font you need.
2. Notice file(s) of a font.
3. Replace its file(s) with another version.

An easy way to find a font is to pipe `fc-list` with `grep`. Here is the example to find Arial font:

```
fc-list | grep --ignore-case arial
```